# What is the default behavior for performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:?

Tags: ios

The documentation for this just says: "Causes the system-provided default behavior to be used."

What is the system default behavior?

I presume the system will check the server's certificate, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the challenge is for server certificate validation (`[challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]`), the system will do the default/safe SSL certificate validation.

Comment: What is the default policy(SSL or BasicX509)?